# Subdomain pointing to a php file but have JS No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, .htaccess

I have the following line for my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index-merchant.php?id=%1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

1) I enter abc.domain.com will be point domain.com/index-merchant.php?id=abc
2) However all JS gives this error - Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
3) I do research on similar case on stackoverflow and other website however the solutions i gotten did not solve this problem.

I tried placing Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*" on .htaccess file but no luck.
Please enlighten me on this issue and where should i place the code at.

Comment: Try `Header set` instead. Are the requests you are doing in your javascript being made to this domain or some other domain like: `www.abc.com`? If so setting a CORS header on your own domain wont work

Comment: Dear Patrick, thank you for your comment. I did try that as well but no luck. Header Set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

Comment: domain.com/index-merchant.php file JS is pointing to same domain but inner folder domain.com/abcfolder/inc/js.php

Comment: domain.com/index-merchant.php have no issue loading the JS and all php include files. However when I access from sub domain abc.domain.com ( which is pointing to index-merchant.php ) all the include JS gives error.